# Erlang - code analysis

Tags: erlang, code-analysis

I have to analyse some existing Erlang code.

Does anybody knows about a tool able to visually / graphically trace the modules calls ?

The behaviour should be : give a directory containing the source code, and get a gui / picture / file of the calls (module1->module2->module3....).

Something like an UML reverse-engineering, but *ala* Erlang ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`xref`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/xref.html) in OTP works like this. It gives you data about which dependencies exist between applications and modules and produces call graphs. [Here's an overview of `xref`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/xref_chapter.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Gradual Typing of Erlang Programs: A Wrangler Experience](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=6&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.erlang.org%2Fworkshop%2F2008%2FSess42.pdf&ei=t3sxSc34IJW20gWZ7ojJCw&usg=AFQjCNFWACgyfEYAnffqgrQO0qclPJGPJw&sig2=BNVd1WMrsnkWFnM6BdSCGA)